JVM blocked with no useful threads infomation
sorry for my pool english.
I have a jar program, I invoke it with java -jar XX.jar, but sometimes this jar is blocked and does not exit nromally, just blocked and without responding, and jstack <PID> does not work, and I have to add -F flag, which is jstack -F <PID> > jstack.log, here is the output:
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.144-b01
Deadlock Detection:

No deadocks found.

Thread 18532: (state=IN_VM)

Thread 18531:(state=BLOCKED)

- java.lang.object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
- java,lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=59, line=143 (Interpreted frame)
- java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2ine=164 (Interpreted frame)
- java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run()@bci=36, line=209 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 18530: (state = BLOCKED)

- java.lang.object.wait(long) @bci=0(Interpreted frame)
- java.lang.obiect.wait() @bci=2,line=502 (Interpreted frame)
- java.iava.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(boolean) @bci=54, 1ine=191 (Interpreted frame)
- java.lang,ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=1, 1ine=153 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 18518: (state=IN_VM)

But I can not find what the JVM is doing, and I find a related article:
https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/unable-to-determine-reason-for-blocked-jvm-5131
could somebody give me some information please?
I use jstack -F to output the jstack info, and I want to find what the JVM is doing.
add my code,
here is my main entrance:
public class UTF8TOGB18030 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args ==null || args.length < 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("please set file name");
        }
        
        String input = args[0].trim();
        if ("".equals(input)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("input is blank.");
        }
        
        FileConverter converter = new FileConverter("UTF-8"，"GB18030"，input, input);
        converter.convert();
    }
}

and here is the util method, and JniUtils is a third-party jar, which use JNI to invoke the linux so library, and I do not have source code.
public class FileConverter {
    public FileConverter(String inputEncoding, String outputEncoding, String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath) {
        this.inputEncoding = inputEncoding;
        this.outputEncoding = outputEncoding;
        this.inputFilePath = inputFilePath;
        this.outputFilePath = outputFilePath;
    }
    public void convert() throws Exception{
        // create temp fileFile 
        File tempOutputFile = new File(outputFilePath + "_" 
            + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMddHHmmssSSs").format (new Date ()));
        String logInfo = "conver begin, input file " + inputFilePath;
        log.info(logInfo);
        logInfo = "conver begin, output file "+ tempOutputFile.getCanonicalPath();
        log.info(logqInfo);

        String ccOpts = inputR + "2" + outputX + "2";
        ccOpts = ccOptS+"??QQNUYYNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN";

        int rsInt = JniUtils.txtFileConv(
            inputEncoding,
            inputFilePath,
            65536,
            outputEncoding,
            tempOutputFile.getCanonicalPath(),
            65536,
            ccOpts,
            "3B3NEI",
            "001",
            "filescheduler",
            "./err.log",
            0);
            
        if(rsint !=0) {
            if(tempoutputFile.exists()) {
                logInfo = "convert error, delete tempOutputFile " + tempOutputrile.getCanonicalPath();
                log.info(logInfo);
                tempOutputFile.delete();
                throw new RuntimeException("convert error, return code is ” + rsint);
            }
        }
        
        tempOutputFile.renameTo(new File(outputFilePath));
    }
}

Additional: Today I use jstack -F -m and find something new:
-------------------1111-------------------------------
0x00007f43a0e0665b  _ZN14AttachListenerl5is_init_triggerEv + 0x4b
0x00007f43a140768d  _ZL19signal thread entryPl0JavaThreadP6Thread + 0x32d
0x00007f43a1560753  _ZN10JavaThread17thread_main_innerEv + 0x103
0x00007f43a156089c  _ZN10JavaThread3runEy + 0x11c
0x00007f43a1411338  _ZL10java_startP6Thread + 0x108

Add some infomation agagin:
Yesterday I get another hung process, which pid is 1079, and I use top -H -p 1079 to see the threads, I find two threads, and each uses 99.5% cpu, the two threads have no stacktrace detail in jstack log, only display (state=IN_VM) like above. And then, I use pstack 1079 to find something, one is blocked in pthread_create@GLIBC_2.2.5, and another is blocked in AttachListener::is_init_trigger().

Hello sd, welcome, and your code is...?.

My dear friend, my dear friend, please edit your question, and add in it, the “minimum” code needed  (in text format) to reproduce your error, so we avoid guessing (for example, what kind of conversion does convert do and on which object does the conversion ) ;).

@MarcePuente I am sorry.. I just add my source code to the question. I ommit some unuseful code, you can ask me for additional information, thanks.

The stack trace indicates that the finalizer thread in your Java application is stuck. If you are using the finalize() method, try debugging if it's taking too long to execute.
Try enabling garbage collection logging to get more details on the garbage collector's behavior.

thanks for your reply, but i do not think so... My program has some log output if the main method invoke, but I did not see anything in the log file when the jvm hung.

Actually, I think that the stacktrace shows that the finalizer and reference threads aren't stuck.  They are waiting to pull work off their respective (empty) queues; i.e. they are idle.
